# SQL queries in php foreach

Tags: php, sql

i have that piece of code.
There is SQL queries in foreach, i know this is not good, but i cant come up with a clue how to optimize this piece of code.
I must check if there is a row with a name **$item['product_name']** and if not - insert into table, and so on
Help me please

```
$sqlData = "";
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $item['product_name'] = str_replace('"', '', $item['product_name']);

            $productData = $this->_conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM product WHERE `name` = '" . $item['product_name'] . "'");
            $warehouseData = $this->_conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM warehouse WHERE `name` = '" . $item['warehouse'] . "'");

            $productData->execute();
            $warehouseData->execute();

            if ($row = $productData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $productID = $row['id'];
            } else {
                $this->_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO product (`name`) VALUES ('" . $item['product_name'] . "')")->execute();
                $productID = $this->_conn->lastInsertId();
            }
            if ($row = $warehouseData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $warehouseID = $row['id'];
            } else {
                $this->_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO warehouse (`name`) VALUES ('" . $item['warehouse'] . "')")->execute();
                $warehouseID = $this->_conn->lastInsertId();
            }

            $tmpItem = implode(',', [$productID, $warehouseID, $item['quantity'], time()]);
            $sqlData .= '(' . $tmpItem . ')';
            if (next($data))
                $sqlData .= ',';
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO wh_quantity (product_id, wh_id, quantity, created_at) VALUES " . $sqlData;
        $this->_conn->prepare($sql)->execute();
```

Comment: Your prepared statements are useless. http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: U mean i can execute that sql without prepare?
but its still not an answer for my question

Comment: I mean that you're not using prepared statements as you should. Right now your statement is totally useless. You could do this with a simple `conn->query()`. With prepared statements you want to put placeholders in your query and then bind variables to it. As I said, visit bobby-tables.com and you'll see what I mean. Its a really good website when it comes to SQL injection & how to prevent them with different languages. And yeah you're right, its not an answer. Thats why I posted it as a comment. Also, your question is off-topic to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sounds like `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`

Comment: @Twinfriends thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If, by optimise, you mean "not run a million select/insert statements in a loop" in order to load a large amount of data into a database, the other way to do it is to load your large amount of data into the database (using whatever bulk-loading facility that database uses) and then run a single SQL statement that compares the data in your bulk loaded table, with the data in the target table

Something like a MERGE query can be used to transfer data from one table to another, updating some rows where a match exists, inserting other rows where no match exists

At the end of the operation, you dump the bulk data you loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should check your If Statements

You have this:

```
  if ($row = $productData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $productID = $row['id'];
        }
```

It should be this ways

```
  if ($row == $productData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $productID = $row['id'];
        }
```

- Single = will assign to variable, but Double = will run a check